# MySQL - Sort by Date in WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sorting, date, sql-update, where-clause

I'm trying to update a row with MySQL but I'm having trouble creating a `WHERE` clause. Here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET clmn = 'some value' 
WHERE date = ?
```

I want to fill in that `?` with the most recent date in the table. How can I do this? I tried using `ORDER BY` but then found out that it's not used in `WHERE` clauses. Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery which finds the most recent date in the table:

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET clmn = 'some value' 
WHERE date = (SELECT t.max_date FROM (SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM tbl) t );
```

Comment: That results in an error: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @jajajajdoajhodjasodjio My updated answer should work.  Tough to remember when MySQL will/will not materialize a subquery.

Comment: Yup just did     :)